# rowMedians functions drops row names

Tags: r

I'm executing the code below and the output ends up dropping the row names.

```
baseMeanPerLvl <- sapply(levels(dds$sensitive), function(lvl) rowMedians( counts(dds,normalized=TRUE)[,dds$sensitive==lvl]))
```

Output:

```
[1,]    2.762384    2.5296235
```

When I run the code with rowMeans instead, I get the expected output:

```
ENSG00000223972.4    3.8508522    3.4101159
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `rowMedians` is not a base R function, please indicate in your question which package it came from. Also, please provide your dataset so others can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`rowMedians` is in the package `robustbase`, while `rowMeans` is part of `base R`. They are likely developed by different people and, therefore, likely operate slightly differently. I might suggest saving the row names before you run your function and applying them later.

```
names.of.rows<-rownames(dds)

baseMeanPerLvl <- sapply(levels(dds$sensitive), function(lvl) rowMedians( counts(dds,normalized=TRUE)[,dds$sensitive==lvl]))

rownames(baseMeanPerLvl)<-names.of.rows
```